# Cannot print data from ngRepeat'ed `textarea`

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/rBGQyOpi9lS0QtnCUq4L

I want to `console.log()` what is being typed in each `textarea` tag. Typing in a `textarea` triggers the `printStuff()` function:

```
        $scope.printStuff=  function(customize,item){
            console.log(customize[item.index].data);
        };
```

When I start typing in any `textarea`, I get this error:

```
angular.js:14290 TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at b.$scope.printStuff (index.html:31)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15118), <anonymous>:4:299)
    at b.$eval (angular.js:17922)
    at angular.js:25653
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:28429)
    at q (angular.js:325)
    at Object.$$writeModelToScope (angular.js:28427)
    at angular.js:28420
    at g (angular.js:28339)
    at f (angular.js:28322)
```

How do I fix this error?

**UPDATED WITH MannFromReno's ANSWER**

I still get the error. Here is my Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/WwC3kNiTQzaQfjp40h2a

Comment: in your latest plucker, you are sending selected.index (the number 0) to printStuff, and the last argument of printStuff is an object "item" with a property index

Comment: @progysm How would I fix this? I'm still pretty new to Angular, so I'm not sure what to do...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't get it where do you get the `index` property. You could use `$index` (provided by `ng-repeat`).

See updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/rOTUoLDWX195Uh0JBXwj

This is the behavior what you want, am I'm right?

Answer (score 2):

Update your textarea binding like

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Paste data here." ng-model="customize[$index].data" ng-change="printStuff($index)"></textarea>
```

and your printStuff function

```
$scope.printStuff = function(index) {
  console.log($scope.customize[index].data);
};
```

One of the mistakes that you were making is, binding to the item.index property which didn't exist. You can use $index inside ng-repeat scope which will give you the current index of iteration.

See this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/kIW3cvbilgptwZT9qtqJ)

Answer (score 2):

You can try below.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app= angular.module("myApp",[]);

  app.controller("myCTRL",function($scope){
   $scope.items= [{}];

   $scope.customize= [{data: 'hi'}];

   $scope.addChart= function(){
    $scope.customize.push({
     data: ''
    });
   };

   $scope.removeChart= function(){
    $scope.items.splice(-1,1);
   };
$scope.removeWhichone = function(id, data){
  //$scope.customize.splice($scope.customize.indexOf(data), 1); 
  angular.forEach($scope.customize, function(value, key) {
            if (key === id){
                $scope.customize.splice(key, 1);
            }
        });
}

   $scope.printStuff= function(customize,index){
   // console.log(customize[index].data);
   };
  });
 </script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCTRL">
 <div>
  <button ng-click="addChart()">Add</button>
  <!--<button ng-click="removeChart()">Remove</button> -->
      
 </div><br>
 <div ng-repeat="item in customize">
  <form novalidate>
   <textarea rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Paste data here." ng-model="customize[$index].data" ng-change="printStuff(customize,$index)"></textarea>
   <button ng-click="removeWhichone($index, item)">Remove</button>
   <br><br>
  </form>
  
 </div>
 {{customize}}
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update it to:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="index = $index;">
    <form novalidate>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Paste data here." ng-model="customize[index].data" ng-change="printStuff(customize, selected.index)"></textarea>
        <br>
    </form>
</div>
```

ng-model should be the data property within customize object and not the object itself as ngModel

Here's a working Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/lqA5Fg8UAz81IM9v3Kts?p=preview

Comment: I'm unsure what is the difference between your answer and the one I accepted several days ago. Can you explain?

Comment: Oh I didn't check the accepted answer really, I just read you said you still had the error and posted the solution.

Answer (score 1):

pass `$index` from the ui as parameter to `printStuff` function

```
<form novalidate>
     <textarea rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Paste data here." ng-   model="$scope.customize[$index]" ng-change="printStuff(customize,item,$index)"></textarea>
    <br>
</form>

$scope.printStuff=  function(customize,item,index){
    console.log(customize[index].data);
};
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/rBGQyOpi9lS0QtnCUq4L?p=preview